# Handling temporary Uri without a UI activity

Tags: android, uri

My app handles Uri shared by the user (registered to `intent.action.SEND` and `intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE`)
I resolve and send these files using TCP but I want to do this completely on the background.

As some Uri's work fine, I've tried sharing a photo from Google Photos and got `Permission Daniel` exception since my activity was destroyed before I finished handling the Uri data.

I've tried starting a service thinking the Uri permission might be 'saved' but I guess it's not.
Is there any way I can handle the Uri without displaying a blocking UI activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to do this completely on the background.

`ACTION_SEND` and `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE` are activity actions. You have no choice but to have an activity that handles them. You are welcome to have that activity use `Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar` to be an "invisible" activity, but it is still there and still takes over the foreground. Usually, such an activity does something short in `onCreate()`, such as kick off some background work and show a `Toast`, then uses `finish()` to go away.

> I've tried starting a service thinking the Uri permission might be 'saved' but I guess it's not

Add `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` on the `Intent` that you use to start the service, and put the `Uri` in the "data" facet of the `Intent`:

```
new Intent(this, YourServiceClass.class)
  .setData(yourUri)
  .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
```

Then, get the `Uri` in the service by calling `getData()` on the `Intent`. The flag will pass the activity's read permission along to the service, which should then be able to use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to read in the content.

Comment: thank you for your response. Looks like adding the data and the flag did the trick and the service can now resolve the data. How do I do this for multiple Uri though? (`ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE`)

Comment: @SagiLow: I'd try `new Intent(getIntent()).setClassName(this, YourServiceClass.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)`. Hopefully the copy constructor copies over the `ClipData` with all the `Uri` values. If that does not work, you'll have to set up the `ClipData` yourself with all the `Uri` values, instead of using `setData()`.

Comment: Just in case someone sees this, the second argument in `setClassName` is the class name and not `Class<?>` so use `YourServiceClass.class.getName()`

Comment: @SagiLow: Ah, sorry. Or, use `setClass()`, which takes the `Class<?>`.

Comment: Nice. Thanks again!